# Monotouch - Display a series of images (too slow)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiview, xamarin.ios, cgcontext

I need to display a series of images as an animation in iOS (using Monotouch). Using 800x600 size images the fastest I can get them to display on my iPad 3 is 160ms (6.25 fps). I would like this to be in the 15-30fps range (< 50ms per image). Reading the image from storage takes < 10ms so it's the drawing to screen that is slow.

```
    public override void Draw (RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);
        var cgimg = UIImage.FromFile (filename).CGImage;
        CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        g.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0, 0, cgimg.Width, cgimg.Height), cgimg);
    }
```

Rendering them as a movie won't provide the interaction speed that I would like (to scrub the frames back and forth)

Is this beyond the hardware limitations? (it doesn't seem like it should be). Do I need to use openGL or Monogame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying OpenGL I ended up drawing directly to the view layer. Instruments is saying 24 FPS using this technique for 800x600 images. (iOS 6.1 on an iPad 3)

```
this.Layer.Contents =  UIImage.FromFile( {filename}).CGImage;
SetNeedsDisplay ();
```

This performed well enough and is about what i expected. The performance goes up to 40+ FPS if the images are displayed a second time (I assume there is caching going on).

Comment: You still shouldn't be calling `UIImage.FromFile` each time the screen is rendered. This is your biggest performance hangup.

Comment: I have to call FromFile because there _might be_ too many images to load into ram.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a couple things to help here:

1. You shouldn't load the `UIImage` in the draw function because that happens very frequently. Set it to a member variable within your class at a time that will happen once for the lifetime of the object such as its constructor, `LayoutSubviews`, or when the `filename` variable is set, etc.
2. You could cache the `CGImage` in this same way as well.
3. Put a `using` statement around the `CGContext` in your `Draw` method.

I think you can get a lot better performance by doing these things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If iOS had enough memory I could cache all the images, but there are probably going to be too many (gigs of used memory). Yes a using statement in all cases is a good idea.